# mobile site redirect to desktop version using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mobile, desktop, redirect

I have a mobile site and it has just started a service for desktop users also. How do I use .htaccess to redirect users using the desktop to the desktop version of the site?

I have tried simple PHP scripts to redirect to the home page of the desktop version, but I would like the redirect to be slightly more efficient. For example, I would like to redirect http://site.com/subfolder/ to http://site.com/desktop/subfolder/, and I figured that using .htaccess might be able to get the job done.

I have tried the following and it doesn't seem to work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/desktop/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!android|!blackberry|!ipad|!iphone|!ipod|!iemobile|!webos|!googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /desktop/ [L,R=302]
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/desktop/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(MSIE.*Windows\ NT|Lynx|Safari|Opera|Firefox|Konqueror) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(^.*(Opera\ Mini|SymbianOS|Mobile)) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /desktop/$1 [L,R=302,NC]
```

## Update (combined with wordpress rules)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^GET\s/wp-login\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(desktop/|wp-admin/|wp-login\.php) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(MSIE.*Windows\ NT|Lynx|Safari|Opera|Firefox|Konqueror) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(^.*(Opera\ Mini|SymbianOS|Mobile)) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /desktop/$1 [L,R=302,NC]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(desktop/|wp-admin/|wp-login\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

R=302 will redirect with https status 302

L will make last rule

NE is for no escaping query string

$1 is your REQUEST_URI

Comment: When i go on the site, it gets redirected to homepage of the desktop version. Also, when i went on the site on my ipod it got redirected too...

Comment: @Adrian Wan: Well I thought your HTTP_USER_AGENT was already validated so I just used it as is from your question. Anyway I just edited my answer above, please try again.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, thank you for your reply, now it is giving me internal server error 500... one thing i should tell you though, i am using wordpress with the site.

Comment: Sorry I had a small typo in code above, just edited again and tested, it is working fine in my browser & iPhone. However I could not test with more mobile devices. Please try and let me know. Also for wordpress do take at this very nice plugin: http://www.bravenewcode.com/store/plugins/wptouch-pro/ (I have been using it and found it really awesome)

Comment: Hi Anubhava, for some reason, it still redirects to http://mysite.com/desktop/ but not http://mysite.com/desktop/subdirectory/....

Comment: oh wait, when i type in a subdirectory it doesn't get redirected at all. the reason that it was redirecting to the homepage was because the redirection was done by the php redirection script.

Comment: Yes that's how it is supposed to behave. For regular browsers it should redirect `mysite.com/foo` to `mysite.com/desktop/foo` but from mobile browsers no redirection must happen and it should remain `mysite.com/foo`. I have tested and verified these conditions from regular browsers and my iPhone browser.

Comment: but when i use regular browser to point to a subdirectory, it does not get redirected at all... only when i type the home address does it get redirected...

Comment: That could be probably result of other rules in your .htaccess file because independently above rules working in all my testing. If you want you can also comment everything but these rules and see if non mobile browsers are redirecting from `mysite.com/foo` to `mysite.com/desktop/foo` or not.

Comment: yes! independently it works great! the following is what i have in my htaccess currently. 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

aren't these required for permalinks to work properly?

Comment: Alright your wordpress rules were indeed causing the problems. I have provided answer in Updated section above by combining wordpress rules and my rules. I have tested them and they seem to be working fine.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much. Would you be able to explain to me the meaning of "Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews"?

Comment: and just one last issue that i don't know how to address, the rules seem to block wp-login.php (which i need to log into the admin panel)... I have tried adding the following rule RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} !^/wp-login\.php$ [NC], 
but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Alright 1 more exception rule like this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/desktop/|wp-admin/|wp-login) [NC]` to take care of wordpress's wp-login.php and wp-admin URLs. If you think it is all working for you can you pls accept this answer.

Comment: hmmm, it's still redirecting me to the login page in the desktop version... :( I don't understand why, the rules seems to make sense...

Comment: There is no problem accessing the wp-admin folder when i have already logged in, but when i am not logged in, it will redirect me to wp-login.php?whateverwhatever and then to /desktop/wp-login.php?whateverwhatever...

Comment: Ok I think I know what was the problem. That desktop condition was at 2 places because of Wordpress rules and I changed only 1 place. Please try again.

Comment: btw: FollowSymLinks tells the web server to follow symbolic links while looking for a file. Multiviews allow substitutions of file extensions, so you can call an URL like www.somehost.org/mypage.php using www.somehost.org/mypage. Apache will figure out there is only on file (mypage.php) matching the request and will serve this instead returning an error 404 - not found. Have a look at this Apache Manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options

Comment: for some reason it's still not working... maybe going to /wp-admin/index.php redirects to another page before going to wp-login.php?

Comment: It shouldn't be since I already have /wp-admin/ in exceptions. Is it still going to `/desktop/wp-login.php?whateverwhatever`? Can you clear your browser's cache and restart it once.

Comment: Yea... it's still going to destop/wp-login.php?whateverwhatever... I have even tried it on a different computer and it's the same... It's not really making sense...

Comment: That's really weird, since I have tested above rules on my host running wordpress and they are behaving as expected and wp-login.php is also working fine.

Comment: Do you think it has anything to do with the fact that desktop is a directory that has another wordpress installation?

Comment: Oh I didn't know about that fact. I will try to simulate this condition on my wordpress and will get back to you.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error but I added 1 more RewriteCond `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^GET\s/wp-login\.php [NC]` above. Please copy/paste Update section code into your .htaccess file and try 1 last time.

Comment: just wondering if it it is possible to have just one wordpress installation, and create a page tree called desktop and have other pages redirect to that instead of the other installation folder?

Comment: would you be able to show me how to do that? WHen i use this set of rule for this, the server shows that page is not found... i guess it's looking for a physical folder....

Comment: If intent is just to show a mobile friendly site to mobile users and otherwise just normal web site then pls take a look at the plug-in i suggested http://bravenewcode.com/store/plugins/wptouch-pro I have been using it for a year and this is an awesome add on to the wordpress installation I manage.

Comment: I already have wptouch installed... the only problem is that I want to show different information on the mobile site vs the desktop version... that's why I wanted to redirect them to the destop version of the page.

Comment: Actually you can already do that using wptouch. If you go to: `http://example.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=wptouch/wptouch.php` then you will see tons of customization you can do for mobile users. You can even show a totally different home page, title etc. And most importantly then you can pick excluded categories to exclude all your desktop specific categories thus giving a totally different content to both set of users.

Comment: Yea, thanks for your advice on that. I will see if i can set that up. The most important thing is still redirection though... if a visitor visits the site at http://site.com/123 is it possible to redirect them to the desktop counterpart of the site?

Comment: With 2 wordpress installations we have already done that :) But even with 1 WP install I believe it can be done, but I just don't have a live demo ready to show you. I will try it out and will get back to you with detailed steps.

Comment: any luck with the new rule? i just can't seem to as wordpress to handle the URL that was entered. Apache tries to look for it in the server...

Comment: Didn't understand the problem, you mean above rules are NOT working even for 2 WP installations for you? Please provide some details what is not working.

Comment: oh, i meant it works for the two installations. Just not the single installation. The problem is when i go to a page, for example /folder1 and gets redirected, apache tries to look for the physical folder on the server (which doesn't exist). but if i were to just type /desktop/folder1 then there would be no problem...

Comment: Alright try changing this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /desktop/$1 [L,R=302,NC]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /desktop/$1 [L,NC]`

Comment: no... it's still saying "The requested URL /d/shows/ was not found on this server." I think it has something to do with "RewriteRule . /index.php [L]" that's in the original wordpress rules, they somehow send the information to the wordpress system via index.php. we probably need to do the same thing here...

Comment: I think that needs to be routed through Wordpress's index.php because it prepares lots of global variables before handing it over to various `.php` files inside the theme you are using. If you want you can check for these user agents in http header inside your theme and route them accordingly. That would not require any .htaccess rules.

Comment: But if I have to do this job, I would simply create a separate landing page for mobile users and keep separate categories for desktop and mobile users. I already told you how you can customize this experience using wptouch's settings page to serve mobile specific home page to mobile users. In my opinion wptouch based handling is much easier and doesn't require any code changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below is target more accuracy at the desktop browsers. You can remove the 1st USER_AGENT line if you don't want to exclude IE 10 on touch based devices.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/desktop/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Windows\ NT.+Touch [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Windows\ NT\ 6|Macintosh|Ubuntu|Linux\ (x86_64|i686)|CrOS [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /desktop/ [L,R]
```

All desktop browsers which are using Windows, Mac, Linux will be redirect to /desktop/.

Answer (score 0):

Were you wanting to redir to the www version of your site? Then change the

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(desktop/|wp-admin/|wp-login\.php) [NC]
```

to the following: (replace the www.example.com with your desktop site).

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

regards

seemore