# Permit only iphone/ipad/ipod/android to access files in directoy, all others redirect to google.com

Tags: android, iphone, .htaccess

I have a directory of MP3 files that I would only like android, iphone, ipad, ipod devices to access, all others be redirected to www.google.com or given a 403 "Forbidden"

I would like to do this with htaccess by reading the user agent.

I have attempted modifying code I found on the net that involved SetEnvIfNoCase or RewriteCond.

Currently I have no code near working and now reaching out for help. Thanks!

Also, I have attempted to modify the code found at [mobile site redirect to desktop version using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698454/mobile-site-redirect-to-desktop-version-using-htaccess) but I couldn't get it correct..

EDIT: Found the solution!

```
    SetEnvIf User-Agent "Android" allow_ua
    SetEnvIf User-Agent "iPhone" allow_ua
    SetEnvIf User-Agent "iPad" allow_ua
    SetEnvIf User-Agent "iPod" allow_ua
    Order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from env=allow_ua
```

Comment: not possible, the only hint in this direction would be user-agent, which is a declarative property (i.e., anyone can put anything)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would like it to view the user agent and then go from there. I know people can forge it, but I'm not looking for something extremely secure, just something so that when a person access the link view mobile device it will display and via desktop it will give them a forbidden or google.com (either would work for me.)

Comment: here is a quick intro as to how to use modrewrite http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/detect-and-redirect-iphone/

Comment: Found the solution, did an edit and posted it.

Comment: Don't edit it, click Answer your question so we don't click on the question thinking it's new.

Comment: Note that this isn't in any way a secure solution, since you can change a user agent to be anything you like when making a request. There are plugins for browsers that allow this, for a start.