# Cant Find error in my .htaccess file ( containing rules for mobile redirection)

Tags: .htaccess

Ok! Now changing the question after digging out some more.
I found out this code so far and when I'm using it, the website hosting server is showing something like Internal server error
This is the txt version of my .htaccess file.

http://www.crosshacks.tk/htaccess.txt

Someone pls help me out.

Comment: You can achieve this using javascript or php (or whatever tech you fancy) to detect users browser agent (or screen resolution) and redirect to mobile version. also, you'll need to a cookie or session to remember users choice of website (desktop or mobile) so he wont get redirected automatically.

Comment: But answering your htaccess question.. there are plenty of answers to that effect. just use the search button. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698454/mobile-site-redirect-to-desktop-version-using-htaccess

Comment: I used search but when i am using the code, and opening the website it is showing error!

Comment: Check detectmobilebrowsers.com

Comment: @gerben: but thats no gonna fix my second problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create a new question instead of editing the old one. Edit is not for creating entirely new questions.

Anyways. You were missing a few spaces.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:www.crosshacks.tk]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         !^m\.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}       !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://m.crosshacks.tk [R,L]
```